# Show custom message without time prefix in <p:schedule>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, schedule

I would like to show a custom message in `<p:schedule>`. It shows the message with time prefix, e.g. "12a CycDemo".

[image]

How can I show only "CycDemo" without time prefix? I'm adding it as follows:

```
model.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("CycDemo", fromDate, toDate));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get one solution. It will not be good solution because of I still cannot find another way.
When I debug the `html` content on the browser by the developer tool, I found the following code.

```
....
<span class="fc-event-time">12a</span>
<span class=".....">CycDemo</span>
...
```

That's why, I solve it by `CSS` `display:none`.

```
.fc-event-time {
    display: none;
}
```

Now, I can only see my expected message without time prefix :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an empty `timeFormat` attribute in `<p:schedule>` then the prefix will disappear.

```
    <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleView.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule" timeFormat="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set AllDay to true of DefaultScheduleEvent

```
DefaultScheduleEvent d = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
d.setAllDay(true);
eventModel.addEvent(d)
```

Comment: Creative solution!